# How to install MongoDB to VS2015 "Blank Node.js Console Application" (TypeScript)

Tags: mongodb, typescript

These are my steps:

- Installed MongoDB
- Open Visual Studio 2015
- Create the project: "File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> "TypeScript" -> "Blank Node.js Console Application"
- Open (as administrator) the project folder in console and type:
  npm install --save mongodb
  npm install --save-dev @types/mongodb
- When I build a project from VS I receive these messages:

> Error Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.
>   Variable 'main' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'NodeModule'.
>   MongodbExp
>   E:_Projects\TypeScript\MongoDB\MongodbExp\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts    91
>
> Error Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. 
>   Variable 'parent' must be of type 'any', but here has type
>   'NodeModule'. MongodbExp
>   E:_Projects\TypeScript\MongoDB\MongodbExp\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts    102
>
> Error Build:Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.
>   Variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type
>   'NodeModule[]'. MongodbExp
>   E:_Projects\TypeScript\MongoDB\MongodbExp\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts
>   103
>
> Error Build:Duplicate identifier 'BufferEncoding'. MongodbExp
>   E:_Projects\TypeScript\MongoDB\MongodbExp\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts
>   123
>
> and so on

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mongodb-exp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "MongodbExp",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "8Observer8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^2.2.30"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^2.2.7",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of typescript are you using ?

Comment: I mean, in your package.json

Comment: Thanky for reply. tsc -v == "2.4.2" I had installed typescript globally. I installed typescript locally, but this did not affect the result in any way.

Comment: I added package.json in the topic.

Comment: VS compiles the files. It has the typescript version == 2.2.2

Comment: I updated typescript for VS from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593 And I updated error messages in topic.

Comment: I solved the problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by these two steps:

- I update TypeScript for Visiao Studio 2015 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593
- I deleted "Scripts/typings" folder